# AWS SDK and CLI behave differently for the same API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-service-catalog

I'm trying to automatically create a new provisioning artifact (or version) for my product in the Service Catalog whenever there's an update.

I checked up the documentation and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ServiceCatalog.html#createProvisioningArtifact-property) seems to be the method I'm looking for. I try it via the AWS CloudShell and it works :

```sh
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-0-150-18 ~]$ aws servicecatalog search-products-as-admin 
{
    "ProductViewDetails": [
        {
            "ProductViewSummary": {
                "Id": "prodview-xxxxxx",
                "ProductId": "prod-xxxxxx",
                "Name": "9ce35033-b4ed-4354-b1f6-ee0f651f7280",
                "Owner": "me@mail.com",
                "Type": "CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE",
                "HasDefaultPath": false
            },
            "Status": "CREATED",
            "ProductARN": "arn:aws:catalog:xxxxxx:xxxxxx:product/prod-xxxxxx",
            "CreatedTime": "2021-10-22T10:33:02+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-0-150-18 ~]$ aws servicecatalog create-provisioning-artifact --product-id prod-xxxxxx --parameters Name=new-version,Info={LoadTemplateFromURL=https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-output/v53/cloud-formation-template.json},Type=CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE
{
    "ProvisioningArtifactDetail": {
        "Id": "pa-xxxxxx",
        "Name": "new-version",
        "Type": "CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE",
        "CreatedTime": "2021-10-22T12:35:57+00:00",
        "Active": true,
        "Guidance": "DEFAULT"
    },
    "Info": {
        "TemplateUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-output/v53/cloud-formation-template.json"
    },
    "Status": "CREATING"
}
```

However, when I use the AWS SDK for JavaScript from my Lambda, and the `createProvisioningArtifact` method, this is what happens :

```js
const updateParams = {
          IdempotencyToken: uuid_1.v4(),
          Parameters: {
            Name: `v${technicalAsset.version}`,
            Info: { LoadTemplateFromURL: outputS3Url },
            Type: "CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE",
          },
          ProductId: existingProductId,
        }
        console.log('updateParams', updateParams);
        const serviceCatalogResponse = await serviceCatalog
            .createProvisioningArtifact(updateParams, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                    serviceCatalogDeploymentStatus = utils_1.AssetServiceCatalogDeploymentStatus.FAILED;
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Successful response from service catalog" + data);
                    serviceCatalogDeploymentStatus = utils_1.AssetServiceCatalogDeploymentStatus.SUCCESSFUL;
                }
            })
            .promise();
```

```
InvalidParametersException: Invalid templateBody. Please make sure that your template is valid
    at Request.extractError (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'InvalidParametersException',
  time: 2021-10-22T10:39:44.319Z,
  requestId: 'bcd23b38-ed62-4684-a392-b9a0ee46f333',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 51.827093801169944
}
```

And in case you think that the `updateParams` is the problem, this what it looks like :

```json
{
  IdempotencyToken: 'b099ca57-47dd-4889-ae71-95d44cc1aae9',
  Parameters: {
    Name: 'v53',
    Info: {
      LoadTemplateFromURL: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-output/v53/cloud-formation-template.json'
    },
    Type: 'CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE'
  },
  ProductId: 'prod-xxxxxx'
}
```

It's a really strange behavior and I'm curious to find out what's behind it... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure this is it, but do the credentials associated with the Lambda function have the appropriate S3 permissions to access the JSON file in S3, like the awscli user that can successfully create the artifact? Or is the JSON file public?

Comment: @jarmod I had my doubts too, but I just checked the execution role and can confirm that the Lambda has full access to S3.

Comment: Could you add code to validate the template you're pointing Service Catalog at? You can do this with the [awscli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/validate-template.html) or just add a small amount of [CFN code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html#validateTemplate-property) to your Lambda.

Comment: Also, does the Lambda have different CloudFormation permissions to the awscli profile you were using?

Comment: Template is valid. And yes the Lambda has limited CF permissions compared to the awscli profile. However I don't think the issue is there because the way the code is designed is that in case that it needs to create products, it can. The problem lies specifically with this method, even though it's CLI counterpart works correctly.

Comment: May be worth adding CloudFormation permissions to the Lambda function role for a quick test. I'm assuming Service Catalog is validating the template on behalf of your Lambda.

Comment: I'm gonna do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS at its finest.
As @jarnod was saying, it was necessary to add the
`cloudFormation:validateTemplate` role to your Lambda execution role if you're using the `createProvisioningArtifact` method.