# Why am I getting a Invalid template body error when building this terraform template for aws service catalog?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-service-catalog

Here is the terraform template for aws service catalog that I am building.

```
resource "aws_servicecatalog_product" "data-ml-pipeline-service-catalog-product" {
  name  = "data-ml-pipeline-service-catalog-product"
  owner = "data-ml"
  type  = "CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE"

  provisioning_artifact_parameters {
    template_url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cf-templates-ozkq9d3hgiq2-us-east-1/temp1.json"
    type  = "CLOUD_FORMATION_TEMPLATE"
  }
```

Based on this question, [Terraform /AWS aws_servicecatalog_portfolio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71062701/terraform-aws-aws-servicecatalog-portfolio), this should work.

Exact error: `Error: error creating Service Catalog Product: InvalidParametersException: Invalid templateBody. Please make sure that your template is valid`

Edit: Here is the new template that I am using.

```
--- 
ModelBuildCodeCommitRepository: 
  Properties: 
    Code: 
      BranchName: main
      S3: 
        Bucket: sagemaker-servicecatalog-seedcode-us-west-2
        Key: toolchain/image-build-model-building-workflow-v1.0.zip
    RepositoryDescription: 
      ? "Fn::Sub"
      : "SageMaker Model building workflow infrastructure as code for the Project ${SageMakerProjectName}"
    RepositoryName: 
      ? "Fn::Sub"
      : "sagemaker-${SageMakerProjectName}-${SageMakerProjectId}-modelbuild"
  Type: "AWS::CodeCommit::Repository"
Parameters: 
  SageMakerProjectId: 
    Description: "Service-generated id of the project"
    NoEcho: true
    Type: String
  SageMakerProjectName: 
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z](-*[a-zA-Z0-9])*"
    Description: "Name of the project"
    MaxLength: 32
    MinLength: 1
    NoEcho: true
    Type: String
```

Comment: I guess you copied the template URL from this example: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/servicecatalog_product. The template URL is not accessible.

Comment: How do I provide a url for the cloud formation template? Will there be a url for a template in a s3 bucket?

Comment: The returned API error message states that the template is invalid, but as @ErvinSzilagyi mentions we do not definitively know the content of the template. Aee you able to share it?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I updated my question with the new template I am using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to provide a general answer to this error message.
AFAIK, `InvalidParametersException: Invalid templateBody. Please make sure that your template is valid` can imply that **AWS cannot access the template** you're trying to create a Service Catalog product version from (the one which is usually provided by key `LoadTemplateFromURL`).
There are 2 possible reasons for this:

- The URL of the template to deploy is invalid. Make sure that the URL provided actually points to a template file. When using Cloudformation with variables inside the URL, make sure to use `!Sub` etc.
- The IAM user/role executing the deployment may not have the required permissions, as seen [in a different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69678431/6312338). Make sure that the permission `cloudFormation:validateTemplate` is in place.

Basically, this error message is misleading because it suggests that the template is invalid but actually the template cannot even be accessed in the 1st place.